# Submission Flutter App Binary Rejected iOS14

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit a new version of my Flutter App into the Apple Store but the binary from my app is being rejected and I'm **not** receiving any email's from Apple informing why. I used to receive them but I have no idea of what is going on.

The problem started since since the iOS14 was released.

Any possible ideas?

My pubspec:

```
name: approachapp
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.2+14

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.11
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
  firebase_database: ^3.1.3
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  device_info: ^0.4.1+4
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.4
  geolocator: ^5.3.2+2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  qr_flutter: ^3.1.0
  flutter_geofire:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/marcuslindemannrohden/flutter_geofire
      ref: update_query
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.6+1
  carousel_slider: ^2.2.1
  google_nav_bar: ^2.2.0
  cloud_functions: ^0.5.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  extended_image: ^0.9.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  hive: ^1.4.4
  path_provider: ^1.6.9
  flutter_mobx: ^1.1.0+1
  mobx: ^1.2.1+1
  flutter_modular: ^1.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  story_view: ^0.12.3
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.1.7



dev_dependencies:
  mockito: ^4.1.1
  modular_codegen: ^1.0.1+3
  mobx_codegen: ^1.1.0+1
  build_runner: ^1.10.0

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/approachlaunchicon.png"

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/

vars:
  runner: flutter pub run build_runner
  clean: flutter clean
  get: flutter pub get

scripts:
  mobb: $clean & $get & $runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
  mobw: $clean & $get & $runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
  updateIcons: flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
  buildAndroidProd: flutter build appbundle --release --flavor prod --target lib/main_prod.dart
  buildiOSProd: flutter build ios --release --flavor prod --target lib/main_prod.dart
```

Comment: You will get a mail soon, or you can check the iTunes account. There will be reason there.

Comment: I haven't received any email since the problem started. I'm just being able to see that it is getting rejected through Push Notification from the official Connect App installed on my phone. But unfortunately, it doesn't let me see the reason through there or the web version...

Comment: open iTunes connect account on Web and check the rejected app. There will be a reason there.